# CKR_GENERAL_ERROR when configuring SunPKCS11 with softhsm

Tags: java, softhsm, sunpkcs11

I'm getting CKR_GENERAL_ERROR when configuring SunPKCS11 with softhsm.

Platform:

- Winodows 10 64bits
- OpenJDK 11.0.2
- https://github.com/disig/SoftHSM2-for-Windows/releases/download/v2.5.0/SoftHSM2-2.5.0.msi

Environment variables:

```
PKCS11_LOGGER_FLAGS=16
PKCS11_LOGGER_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\SoftHSM2\lib\softhsm2-x64.dll
```

VM arguments:

```
-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11
```

Java code:

```java
String aPKCS11LibraryFileName = "C:\\\\Development\\\\pkcs11-logger\\\\pkcs11-logger-x64.dll";

StringBuilder pkcs11Config = new StringBuilder();
pkcs11Config
    .append("name = token1")
    .append(NEW_LINE)
    .append("library = ")
    .append(DOUBLE_QUOTE)
    .append(aPKCS11LibraryFileName)
    .append(DOUBLE_QUOTE);

Provider provider = Security.getProvider("SunPKCS11");
Method configureMethod = provider.getClass().getMethod("configure", String.class);
provider = (Provider) configureMethod.invoke(provider, "--" + pkcs11Config.toString());
Security.addProvider(provider);

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(SUN_PKCS11_KEYSTORE_TYPE, provider);
keyStore.load(null, "1234".toCharArray());
```

Console output:

```
SunPKCS11 loading --name = token1
library = "C:\\Development\\pkcs11-logger\\pkcs11-logger-x64.dll"
sunpkcs11: Initializing PKCS#11 library C:\Development\pkcs11-logger\pkcs11-logger-x64.dll
sunpkcs11: Multi-threaded initialization failed: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_GENERAL_ERROR
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at ar.gob.hcssf.isileg.tokengateway.PKCS11MockTest.start(PKCS11MockTest.java:51)
    at ar.gob.hcssf.isileg.tokengateway.PKCS11MockTest.main(PKCS11MockTest.java:29)
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:382)
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11$1.run(SunPKCS11.java:113)
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11$1.run(SunPKCS11.java:110)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.configure(SunPKCS11.java:110)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_GENERAL_ERROR
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_Initialize(Native Method)
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11$SynchronizedPKCS11.C_Initialize(PKCS11.java:1549)
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.getInstance(PKCS11.java:160)
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:336)
    ... 10 more
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : ****************************** 2021-04-25 00:11:33 ***
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : PKCS11-LOGGER 2.2.0
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : PKCS#11 logging proxy module
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Developed as a part of the Pkcs11Interop project
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Please visit www.pkcs11interop.net for more information
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : ****************************** 2021-04-25 00:11:33 ***
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Successfuly loaded C:\SoftHSM2\lib\softhsm2-x64.dll
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Memory contents are dumped without endianness conversion
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : ****************************** 2021-04-25 00:11:33 ***
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Calling C_GetFunctionList
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Input
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :  ppFunctionList: 0000024C156047D8
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Output
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :  Note: Returning function list of PKCS11-LOGGER
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Returning 0 (CKR_OK)
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : ****************************** 2021-04-25 00:11:33 ***
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Calling C_Initialize
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Input
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :  pInitArgs: 0000024C152539C0
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :   CreateMutex: 0000000000000000
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :   DestroyMutex: 0000000000000000
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :   LockMutex: 0000000000000000
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :   UnlockMutex: 0000000000000000
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :   Flags: 2
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :    CKF_LIBRARY_CANT_CREATE_OS_THREADS: FALSE
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :    CKF_OS_LOCKING_OK: TRUE
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :   pReserved: 0000000000000000
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Returning 5 (CKR_GENERAL_ERROR)
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : ****************************** 2021-04-25 00:11:33 ***
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Calling C_GetFunctionList
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Input
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :  ppFunctionList: 0000024C1562A7E8
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Output
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :  Note: Returning function list of PKCS11-LOGGER
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Returning 0 (CKR_OK)
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : ****************************** 2021-04-25 00:11:33 ***
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Calling C_Initialize
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Input
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 :  pInitArgs: 0000000000000000
0x000085a0 : 0x00007750 : Returning 5 (CKR_GENERAL_ERROR)
```

softhsm2-util.exe:

```
C:\SoftHSM2\bin>softhsm2-util.exe --show-slots
Available slots:
Slot 1309549255
    Slot info:
        Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x4e0e22c7
        Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
        Hardware version: 2.5
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Token present:    yes
    Token info:
        Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
        Model:            SoftHSM v2
        Hardware version: 2.5
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Serial number:    48ed68114e0e22c7
        Initialized:      yes
        User PIN init.:   yes
        Label:            My token 2
Slot 2134878761
    Slot info:
        Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x7f3faa29
        Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
        Hardware version: 2.5
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Token present:    yes
    Token info:
        Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
        Model:            SoftHSM v2
        Hardware version: 2.5
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Serial number:    169a27c97f3faa29
        Initialized:      yes
        User PIN init.:   yes
        Label:            My token 1
Slot 2
    Slot info:
        Description:      SoftHSM slot ID 0x2
        Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
        Hardware version: 2.5
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Token present:    yes
    Token info:
        Manufacturer ID:  SoftHSM project
        Model:            SoftHSM v2
        Hardware version: 2.5
        Firmware version: 2.5
        Serial number:
        Initialized:      no
        User PIN init.:   no
        Label:

C:\SoftHSM2\bin>
```

Before this I've tried using [pkcs11-mock](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/pkcs11-mock). Provider was successfully configured but it never ends when keystore.load() is executed.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setting SOFTHSM2_CONF environment variable in launcher, the provider was successfully configured and keystore could load instantly.

It seems not getting system environment variable.

Comment: Setting the environment variable is one solution.  The other is having a softhsm2 config file in ~/.config/softhsm2/softhsm2.conf